# Zoom-SVD using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-analysis, quantitative-finance, dimensionality-reduction

I have come across this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00754.pdf about a new SVD algorithm called **Zoom-SVD**.

I was wondering how to create the Zoom-SVD architecture in Python?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is very broad and unlikely to elicit any answers.